# Wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have had a little search and maybe I am searching for the wrong thing. I am trying to run a function from my functions.php file in wordpress and assign the returned array to a variable.

When I run the function, it just echos out the returned data rather than assigning it to the variable.

I'm assuming this is a Wordpress thing.

Code from functions.php

```
function get_portfolioBlock( ) {
 $portfolio_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'name' => 'test1'));
 if ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ($portfolio_query->have_posts() ) {

         $portfolio_query->the_post();
         $portfolio_block = array('title' => the_title(), 'excerpt' => the_excerpt() );
     }
     return $portfolio_block;
 } else {
     return 'error';
 }
```

}

The code in my template file

```
<?php $portfolio = get_portfolioBlock(); ?>
```

When the page loads it automatically loads the data into the page without assigning the variable for me to use else where

Comment: wp functions: `the_whatever()` will do output. `get_the_whatever()` will RETURN instead of outputting.

Comment: If I put get_the_get_portfolioBlock I get the undefined function error. Where do I need to put the get_the? As the function name?

Comment: no. `$portfolio_query->get_the_post()`

Comment: `->the_post()` is correct, just use `get_the_title()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gerald!

The reason for it echoing in out the function was because when I was assigning the_title and the_excerpt I should have been using

```
get_the_title() and get_the_excerpt()
```